# Errors with ActionBarSherlock TabListener class

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, runtime-error

I'm trying to develop an app which uses Tabs to navigate from one section to another.

But I'm getting errors trying to implement an ActionBarSherlock TabListener class. IntelliJ keeps suggesting that I need to implement the methods into the class, but they're already there. Then when I compile I get another set of errors.

Pastebin link for errors: http://pastebin.com/v00kN5p8

### **MyActivity.java**

http://pastebin.com/SMgMw31h

### **FragmentFirst.java**

http://pastebin.com/AKVMjbY2

### **FragmentSecond.java**

http://pastebin.com/bmKTPa0y

Comment: Links can be useful as supplemental information, but all the relevant information should be included in the question, as there is no guarantee that the links will always be available. Also, rather than asking people to read all your code, narrow it down to [the parts relevant to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use support library. change your imports  `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`  instead 'android.app.FragmentTransaction' same as for fragments

Comment: create new methods from suggestion and if method contain any code then cut code from previous method and paste into new method.

Comment: @user3337034 When I try to add the imports, IntelliJ says it cannot resolve it.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I've doing that to no avail.

Comment: @NotoriousArab have you `android-support-v4.jar`. add this jar. it will resolved error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by completely reinstalling IntelliJ (and resetting all settings) and made sure all the imports were actually coming from the ActionBarSherlock library.

Also, made sure that the "Export" button was **checked** in the Project Structure window under the ActionBarSherlock library in modules.

[image]